# Python pandas multiply columns from two dataframes to get a number for each row (group)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix-multiplication

I am using Python, and would like to get a calculated number **(price * ratio)** from two data frames for each group:

**Table 1:** `df1`

| Group | Category | price_1 | price_2 | price_3 | price_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | Single | 20.1 | 19.8 | 19.7 | 19.9 |
| a | Multi | 25.1 | 26.8 | 24.7 | 24.9 |
| b | Multi | 27.1 | 27.8 | 27.7 | 26.9 |

**Table 2:** `df2`

| Group | Category | ratio_1 | ratio_2 | ratio_3 | ratio_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | Single | 1.0 | 0.8 | 0.7 | 0.5 |
| a | Multi | 1.0 | 0.7 | 0.6 | 0.4 |
| b | Multi | 1.0 | 0.7 | 0.5 | 0.3 |

**Desired Output:** `df`

| Group | Category | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | Single | 59.68 |
| a | Multi | 68.64 |
| b | Multi | 68.48 |

Example, for Group = 'b' and Category = 'Multi', value = 27.1 * 1.0 + 27.8 * 0.7 + 27.7 * 0.5 + 26.9 * 0.3 = 68.48

How may I get that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split) to create a MultiIndex on `df1` and `df2` (columns and index) then use math operations to compute the value column:

```
# Create MultiIndex on df1 and df2
idx_cols = ['Group', 'Category']
df1 = df1.set_index(idx_cols)
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.rsplit('_', n=1, expand=True)
df2 = df2.set_index(idx_cols)
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.rsplit('_', n=1, expand=True)

# Compute DF3
df3 = df1['price'].mul(df2['ratio']).sum(axis=1).reset_index(name='value')
```

`df3`:

```
  Group Category  value
0     a   Single  59.68
1     a    Multi  68.64
2     b    Multi  68.48
```

`df1` becomes:

```
               price                  
                   1     2     3     4
Group Category                        
a     Single    20.1  19.8  19.7  19.9
      Multi     25.1  26.8  24.7  24.9
b     Multi     27.1  27.8  27.7  26.9
```

And `df2` becomes:

```
               ratio               
                   1    2    3    4
Group Category                     
a     Single     1.0  0.8  0.7  0.5
      Multi      1.0  0.7  0.6  0.4
b     Multi      1.0  0.7  0.5  0.3
```

`pandas` will correctly align columns and index to perform appropriate multiplication.

---

IF AND ONLY IF the DataFrames are already aligned correctly can simply do the operations using the Group and Category columns from one of the DataFrames and use [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas-dataframe-to-numpy) to multiply the two dataframes together ignoring the column index and [`np.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) to compute the totals:

```
df3 = df1[['Group', 'Category']].copy()
df3['value'] = np.sum(
    df1.filter(like='price_').to_numpy() * df2.filter(like='ratio_').to_numpy(),
    axis=1
)
```

`df3`:

```
  Group Category  value
0     a   Single  59.68
1     a    Multi  68.64
2     b    Multi  68.48
```

This method is much faster and takes up less space, but requires the DataFrames `df1` and `df2` to already be aligned correctly (as they are in the OP) but is much less robust in handling errors than the former. However, this is optimal if the conditions have been met.

Comment: Thanks Henry! If df1 and df2 have different dimensions of 'Group' and 'Category'. Will that work for those matched ones?

Comment: The first option should work quite generally and align well regardless of dimensions of either dataframe.

Comment: Thanks! I believe that shall work, just that there was an error: '<' not supported between instances of 'bytes' and 'str'.  I think it's because 'Group' and 'Category' are 'objective' dtypes instead of 'string'. Wasn't able to convert them by trying some ways, but that could be a separate question.

Comment: That cannot have come from the provided sample data. For that reason, I don't know where the error could be coming from. As you have 3 answers which work for the provided sample set, but all fail in some way due to a misunderstanding of Data representation, I'd suggest a new question which has actual code constructors. Something that can be copied into a blank python workspace and build an _exact_ representation of the data you're working with rather than the markdown tables on StackOverflow which do not include dtype information.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry I couldn't help on this thread. But changing the question to include more representative data now would invalidate 3 answers, so I think it'd be best to try in a new thread.

Answer (score -1):

Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Group': list(df1['Group']), 'Category': list(df1['Category']), 'value': df1['price_1']*df2['ratio_1'] + df1['price_2']*df2['ratio_2'] + df1['price_3']*df2['ratio_3'] + df1['price_4']*df2['ratio_4']})
```

Output:

```
Group Category  value
0     a   Single  59.68
1     a    Multi  68.64
2     b    Multi  68.48
```

Comment: Thank you! This's clear. Just got and error: ValueError: array length 333 does not match index length 886. though datatype shall match, will think more.

Comment: It will wo only if the size of data frame and columns is same.